# Is there a performance gain for final variables?

Tags: dart

Yeah, the title. Is there any difference (other than design, obviously) when writing `final` or not?

Comment: That's the thing. Say I have a property that is conceptually final. Later, I need to replace the whole object, but since I need the reference to that object, I instead have to go reassigning all the properties again -- basically call the constructor without actually making a new object. I know it **should** be final, but I can't make it that.

Comment: Also, what I really meant memory-wise, since I see A LOT of classes in Flutter are to optimize away little memory things, so I thought it might make a difference

Comment: (1) if you have to update it later, it's not `final`.  (2) first make it work.  If there's a problem fix it once you know it's a problem. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). ([why?](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/))

Comment: I know why it doesn't work, and what can be done, etc. It's working now. I just want to know if I should try to find a way to dispose the whole object and make a new one that has final fields. You know, since that seems to be how dart likes it

Comment: A `final` variable is a variable that cannot be reassigned, not a variable that cannot be mutated.  Therefore I think it's unlikely that there would be any optimization opportunities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both "final" and "const" keywords may improve performance and reduce APK size for applications built in Flutter. "const" `Widget`s have a different lifespan that improves performance.

Using these keywords indeed does some good. Though `final` specifically may be misleading, and the compiler often knows the variable is never reassigned without the keyword. The improvements might not be worth the time. It is a matter of personal taste

I personally stick to using them, because no matter how small it seems, all performance issues are known to stack up and snowball.

Comment: Thanks! As @jamesdlin noted above (and I should have specified), my use case involves final properties, with the actual object being a non-final property of a final object. So even though the object itself will not be final, will making the fields final have the same effect?

Comment: @LeviLesches Yep, it will.

Comment: @LeviLesches in my flutter applications I declare all fields for a class final. If I need to update it, I create a new instance with a custom constructor classname.from(classname other {data data}) => classname(data = data??classname.data). In this case I declare the class final too so I don't face your problem :D

Comment: I would like to do that, but with my use case, there are widgets that have references to those objects and I can't just replace them

Comment: Anyway, wherever you can use keywords such as show, const, final, var instead of dynamic - use them, they exist for a reason ;D

Comment: Actually, does show do anything important besides preventing namespace collision? I used to think it reduces import overhead, but I'm not so sure

Comment: By the way, I'm really surprised how all these people stick to "readability" (basically laziness) instead of performance. They downvoted your question when you asked about syntax+performance, lol. Indeed modern processors can handle bad code, but in big apps it will snowball to real problems.

Comment: yes, "show" does. namespace collision is prevented by "as" which imports every class from a library, show only imports 1

Comment: Right I meant by using show does the compiler optimize what it needs to import, resulting in faster and smaller apps?

Comment: I believe so. However I did not ever test it so that might be speculative. Well, atleast building apk will be faster for sure :D

Comment: Minify: true for android will delete unused classes, but if it's set to false "show" might SHOW some performance gain :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198565/discussion-between-levi-lesches-and-alexey-subbotin).

Answer (score 2):

As Flutter framework is build around immutability, the `final` keyword is a way to enforce that immutability. So it is help ensure the following of Flutter design patterns.

In other hand , the Dart compiler do some optimizations that would not be possible if variable was marker `var`