# Does final keyword improve performance on a local variable in Dart?

Tags: performance, dart, final

EDIT: I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633479/is-there-a-performance-gain-for-final-variables), but IMO no-one has answered it with any authority or certainty... and also that question is more general.

Please either have an authoritative reference or actually know how the Dart compiler works (cuz I sure don't) :D

Let's say in Dart we have:

```
_myFunction() {

     int foo = 5; // don't plan on changing it

}
```

I'm assuming that in general, aside from its obvious purpose, there is a performance advantage to declaring a variable final because the compiler would know you never plan to change the variable and would optimize somehow.

In a case like this where foo is a local variable (its just going to be thrown out very quickly anyway), is there any actual performance improvement by declaring foo final instead... or is it just "good practice"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a performance gain for final variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633479/is-there-a-performance-gain-for-final-variables)

Comment: It makes zero difference.  I'm pretty sure that lrn has commented to the same effect somewhere, but consider this: it's *trivial* for a modern compiler to detect if a local variable is never reassigned, so if there were an optimization opportunity, the compiler could automatically just do it for you.